# How to change postgresql database configuration on keycloak-10.0.1

Tags: postgresql, keycloak

**How to connect with postgresql database in keycloak? by-default keycloak is use H2 database but we have to change the database from H2 to postgresql so i request you please help to connect with postgresql database in keycloak.**

1). I have put the postgresql jar and mudule.xml file in below path:-

`D:\Users\itteam\Downloads\keycloak-10.0.1\modules\system\layers\keycloak\org\postgresql`

2). module.xml

```
                <?xml version="1.0" ?>
                <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.postgresql">
                
                    <resources>
                        <resource-root path="postgresql-9.4.1212.jar"/>
                    </resources>
                
                    <dependencies>
                        <module name="javax.api"/>
                        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
                    </dependencies>
                </module>
```

3). standalone.xml

```
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                                      ​<connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/keycloak-dev</connection-url>
                                      ​<driver>postgresql</driver>
                                      ​<pool>
                                          ​<max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                                      ​</pool>
                                      ​<security>
                                          ​<user-name>postgres</user-name>
                                          ​<password>password</password>
                                      ​</security>
                                  ​</datasource>
                                <drivers>
                                    <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                                         ​<xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                                     ​</driver>
                                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                                    </driver>
                                </drivers>
                            </datasources>
```

4). After running standalone.conf.bat file then i am getting the below error logs please help me.

Calling `"D:\Users\itteam@tekmindz.com\Downloads\keycloak-10.0.1\bin\standalone.conf.bat"`
Setting JAVA property to `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java"`

```
                  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
                
                  JBOSS_HOME: "D:\Users\itteam@tekmindz.com\Downloads\keycloak-10.0.1 - postgresql"
                
                  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java"
                
                  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman "
                
                                
                20:37:15,516 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.10.0.Final
                20:37:16,438 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.11.Final
                20:37:16,454 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
                20:37:16,626 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 10.0.1 (WildFly Core 11.1.1.Final) starting
                20:37:18,688 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.11.4.Final
                20:37:19,095 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) OPVDX002: Failed to pretty print validation error: null
                20:37:19,095 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
                        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:143)
                        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:392)
                        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
                Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Received non-all-whitespace CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag().
                 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [150,8]
                        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:650)
                        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:204)
                        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
                        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69)
                        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_10.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml_10.java:587)
                        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_10.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_10.java:222)
                        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_10.readElement(StandaloneXml_10.java:119)
                        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:126)
                        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:52)
                        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122)
                        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:76)
                        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:126)
                        ... 3 more
                Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Received non-all-whitespace CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag().
                 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [150,8]
                        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:634)
                        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:504)
                        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:488)
                        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1223)
                        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:152)
                        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parseDataSource_4_0(DsParser.java:1927)
                        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:229)
                        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:189)
                        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:643)
                        ... 14 more
                
                20:37:19,095 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
                20:37:19,126 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 10.0.1 (WildFly Core 11.1.1.Final) stopped in 21ms
                Press any key to continue . . .
```

**by-default keycloak uses H2 database but we have to change the database from H2 to postgresql so i request you please help to connect with postgresql database in keycloak**

Answer (score 0):

I switched my text editor to PyCharm and it showed a few non-visible characters which I deleted and the parsing of the configuration file was successful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29830515)